# How to use more than 200 nested if conditions in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have the following data in excel sheet A.

```
Category    Name
Fruit       Apple
Vegetable   Brinjal
XYZ         Abc
```

I want to create a formula which takes a value for name column, outputs the  corresponding category column.

If I use VLookUp, I have to copy this reference table in each and every excel sheet wherever I need to have this operation.

Hence I am looking for something similar to

```
IF(input="Apple","Fruit",IF(input="Brinjal","Vegetable",IF(input="Abc",XYZ,"")))
```

But There is limit on nested ifs in excel and no of cases that we can have in a switch case are also limited.

I have around 200 rows of this table.

Comment: Don't.  Just copy the reference table.  Put it in it's own sheet, along with anything else you need and just copy the whole sheet into your new workbooks.

Comment: It doesnt have to be in each sheet, you can reference one sheet from another. Put all of your lookup data in one sheet and then refer to it from other sheets.

Comment: I dont want to copy these columns  whenever I required. I just want these data into formula, so that I will just apply formula every time.

Answer (score 2):

use INDEX and MATCH functions. INDEX on "category" by matching "name"

Comment: In this case I need to have reference table in each document right?

Comment: I thought all this in in the same workbook "document". ie: Index(A:A,match("input name",B:B,0))

Comment: @ShivaN - Use something like, `=INDEX({"Fruit","Vegetable","Xyz"},MATCH(A1,{"Apple","Brinjal","Abc"},0))`

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need so many IF statements (though I note your Q Title), for example:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(D13,{"Apple","Brinjal","Abc"},0),"Fruit","Vegetable","XYZ")
```

which should not grow at quite the rate your version would - but with 200 'pairs' would be getting close to the limit for [CHOOSE](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/choose.php).

(`D13` as example in spreadsheet.)

Comment: As I mentioned in the Question, I have 200 rows in the reference sheet.